# how to resize custom task pane an on word document resize?

Tags: c#, interop, cpu-word

I have added custome task pane into I docked windows usercontrol and windows usercontrol contains wpf user control.In wpf user control I have added webview2 to render the UI by using url.But when I resize custome task pane it doesn't resize form also it doesn't resize on word application minimize and maximize.

Answer (score 0):

CustomTaskPane automantically gets resized to fit the Word's height, the problem is the controls in the CTP will not.

If your question targets the controls in CTP, I suggest you to set the Dock property of those controls. Please check following code:

```
UserControl userControl = new UserControl() { AutoScroll = true };

        RichTextBox rt = new RichTextBox();
        
        rt.Dock=DockStyle.Fill;

        Panel pane = new Panel();
        pane.Controls.Add(rt);
        pane.Height = 100;
        userControl.Controls.Add(pane);
        CustomTaskPane customTaskPane = this.CustomTaskPanes.Add(userControl, "Description");
        customTaskPane.Visible = true;
```